How can i deep copy and shallow copy any object safely in .net maui
I want to fully copy a control in maui .How can i do that .I tried the following code but it returns error
I tried this to copy an control :
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace CrossPlatformLibrary.CSExtended.CSESystem
{
    public class CSEObject
    {
        public object ShallowCopy(object o)
        {
            return o?.GetType().GetMethod("MemberwiseClone", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)?.Invoke(o, null);
        }

        public object Copy(object o)
        {
            return DeepCopy(o);
        }
        public static object DeepCopy(object o)
        {
            JsonSerializerOptions jsonOptions;

            jsonOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions();

            jsonOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());

            var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(o, jsonOptions);
            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize(json, o.GetType(), jsonOptions);
        }
    }
}

but it threw exception :
System.NotImplementedException


What method throws the exception?

DeepCopy() throws error in maui
.Also ShallowCopy() throws exceptions
If this method is not reliable then show me another reliable standard way

Here's my solution using reflection to solve the problem. It implements the functionality for both deep copy and shallow copy of properties.
   public static T ShallowCopy<T>(T original)
   {
       if (original == null)
       {
           return default(T);
       }
       Type type = original.GetType();
       object copy = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
       foreach (PropertyInfo property in type.GetProperties())
       {
           if (property.CanRead && property.CanWrite)
           {
               try
               {
                   var value = property.GetValue(original);
                   property.SetValue(copy, value);       
               }
               catch (NotImplementedException) { }
               catch (Exception e){}             
           }

       }
       return (T)copy;
   }

   public static T DeepCopy<T>(T original)
   {
       if (original == null)
       {
           return default(T);
       }
       Type type = original.GetType();
       object copy = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
       foreach (PropertyInfo property in type.GetProperties())
       {
           if (property.CanRead && property.CanWrite)
           {
               try
               {
                   var value = property.GetValue(original);
                   if (property.PropertyType.IsValueType || property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                   {
                       property.SetValue(copy, value);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       var deepCoptyValue = DeepCopy(value);
                       property.SetValue(copy, deepCoptyValue);

                   }
               }
               catch (NotImplementedException) { }
               catch (Exception e){}              
           }

       }

       return (T)copy;
   }

